# Is there a free tool to generate a XSLT template based on one XSD file?

Tags: xslt, xsd

The tool I am looking for should be able to generate a XSLT template based upon one XSD file (target = source). Without changes to the template the execution of the XSLT would result in a XML file that is exactly the same as the source.
My goal is to use the template and do minor changes to the sequence of tags in the result XML-file.
The reason I need this is that the legacy system we use, requires a strict pre defined sequence of the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such tools. In any case, I don't understand why you need it in the first place - just use the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Example_using_XSLT), which is universal for any input document, and then add template rules for cases that you need to handle specially.